# wp_mail() is not working in localhost

Tags: plugins, wp-mail, localhost

I'm trying to test wp_mail() in my local.
When I var dump wp_mail,I get Boolean false.This is my code

```
    $to = "abcd@gmail.com";
    $subject = 'my subject';
    $message = 'I would like to work with you';
    $headers = '';


    $sent_message = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    var_dump($sent_message); // i get boolean false here.
    if ( $sent_message ) {
        echo 'The test message was sent. Check your email inbox.';
    } else {
        echo 'The message was not sent!'; //this gets printed in d end.
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

`wp_mail()` falls back to php's `mail()` function which requires a configured MTA (Message Transfer Agent) on your host. So either you install and configure such a MTA. If you're running a Linux like OS, [SSMTP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP) is an easy solution on which you can use any mail-provider to send your system mails via SMTP. Another MTA would be [Sendmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sendmail), a full featured, yet difficult to configure MTA.

Or you simply use a plugin like [WP Mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) which implements a direct SMTP connection in PHP and bypass the `mail()` usage.

Comment: If you just want to test mail functionality while developing you can use mailcatcher: https://mailcatcher.me Didn't test it on windows - but on Mac os it running. On other linux os it should work as well.

Answer (score 6):

If anybody stumbles across this old question:

In my case, the reason was, I gave the site at localhost a name without a top-level domain. e.g. "mysite" (instead of "mysite.com"). So, WordPress assumed the "From" address to be "wordpress@mysite".

Phpmailer (which is called by wp_mail) then raised the error: "Invalid address: (From): wordpress@mysite"

Solution was to explicitly set the from address via the header:

```
    $headers[] = 'From: Wordpress<wordpress@mysite.com>';
    $sent_message = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Then wp_mail worked.

Comment: Works fine. Good solution!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Ronni's helpful answer, here's how you can override the `From:` address for all outgoing mail:

```php
if (defined('WP_CLI')) {
    WP_CLI::add_wp_hook('wp_mail_from', function () {
        return 'my@addr.com';
    });
} else {
    add_filter('wp_mail_from', function () {
        return 'my@addr.com';
    });
}
```

For my local development environment, I found it useful to place it in `wp-config.php`, at the very bottom, after `require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';`.

Added a workaround for wp-cli, since it doesn't provide `add_filter()` like WP would normally do.